# Render into a 3D Texture

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, 3d, glsl

I want to render a set of points into a 3D texture. But somehow I don't write in it. With glGetTexImage() I only get 0 for every entry. I am storing the 3D Texture in a Framebuffer and with a different render pass I want to read out informations out of the 3Dtexture stored in the frame buffer.

```
Initialization of the FrameBuffer.
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);


glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

glFramebufferTexture3D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture, 0, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    std::cout << "FBO successfully loadet" << std::endl;
}else{
    std::cout << "FBO had en ERROR" << std::endl;
}
```

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main(){

    gl_PointSize = 1.0;

    gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);

}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){

    fragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0);

}
```

Before that I tried it with a normal render pass and storing these points separately in a 3D texture. That seemed to work. But now with the frame buffer it writes only 0's.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. You can only render to one layer of a 3d texture, not to the whole texture.

Comment: SO do I have to render for each layer separately? it would be 256 time. And How do I render to a certain layer?

Comment: YOu already do render to a specific layer, that is hat `glFrameBufferTexture3D`'s `layer` parameter is for. You might be able to get something out of using _layered_ framebuffers, but you won't be able to render to 256 layers in a single pass.

Comment: so if I choose layer 10 for example with glFrameBufferTexture3D and then render, I would render only a 2D texture of GRID_SIZE*GRID_SIZE. And if a choose layer 11, and render again, I have in my frame buffer 2 layers of 2 2D texture, at position 10 and 11 ? How can I read out what is written in my buffer or texture? I think I have there something wrong to

Comment: I mean I am loading a 3DTexture in it. How does this work? If I iterate 256 times with GL_TEXTURE_3D does he load every time a 3D texture or do I have to load with GL_TEXTURE_2D for each layer?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a compute shader to write all your points to your texture 3D with a single call to glDispatchCompute:

- write the 3D coordinates of the points you want to update in an SSBO or a texture1D
- bind your SSBO/texture1D and your texture3D
- bind your compute shader which should look like this:

```
#version 430
layout (binding=0, rgba16i) readonly uniform image1D points
layout (binding=1, rgba16f) writeonly uniform image3D tex3D

void main()
{
    ivec3 point_coords = imageLoad(points, gl_GlobalInvocationID.x).xyz;
    imageStore(tex3D, point_coords, vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0));
}
```

- call glDispatchCompute(pointCount, 0, 0);
- call glMemoryBarrier() with the param bitfield set to whatever you intend to do with your texture3D (when unsure GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS is good way to start)